# Pure Javascript version of jQuery mouseenter *

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent

I looked through the jQuery code but it's a bit hard to follow.

I'm looking for a pure JS implementation of the following jQuery event:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '*', function(ev){
    console.log( ev.target );
});
```

I could not determine if the above is just mousemove with element checking or not (would seem terribly inefficient if so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addEventListener`

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
  //your code 
})
```

Comment: I don't mean element specific; I mean global; is that possible?

Comment: You can add the listener in the window, edited the answer see if it solves for you

Comment: I did try window originally and it didn't work; apparently mouseenter / mouseleave are jQuery specific; the native methods are mouseover / mouseout and they work with window.

Comment: This is NOT like jquery's version. Jquery uses mouseover/out with timers under the hood, to be able to give real event delagation (which isn't available/possible on native es mouseenter, due to lack of bubbling).